# SAP receive adapter high availability

Tags: biztalk

We are having a active-active BizTalk cluster with windows server as software load balancer. The solution includes a SAP receive adapter accepting inbound rfc calls. The goal is to make SAP adapter high availabile.

Read the documentation (), it does says 'You must always cluster the SAP receive adapter to accommodate a two-phase commit scenario.' and 'hosts running the receive handlers for FTP, MSMQ, POP3, SQL, and SAP require a clustering mechanism to provide high availability.'

What we currently did in both the active-active node for BizTalk, we have a host instance enabled. With refering to above documentation, does it mean we did it incorrectly? We should take the clustered host instance instead the active-active deployment?

thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cluster the host that handles the SAP receive. What this means is that you will always have only one instance of the adapter running at any given time and if one of the server goes down, the other will pick up.

Compare this with your scenario where you simply have two (non-clustered) instances running concurrently: yes, this gives you high availability - but also deadlocks! The two will run independently of each other... With the cluster scenario above, they will run one at the time

To cluster the SAP receive host: open the admin console, find the host, right-click and Cluster.